# Excel Formulas won't work

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to combine

```
=IF('Attendance Tracker'!B52=0,"Y",IF('Attendance Tracker'!B52=1,"T",IF('Attendance Tracker'!B52>=2,"N")))
```

and

```
=IF('Attendance Tracker'!D52>=0.1,"N",IF('Attendance Tracker'!E52>0.1,"N")).
```

Each formula works ok separately but they I can't get them to work together or add the formulas together where they will work.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't referencing the same cell. I *think* you want to check first B52 for 0, then B52 for 1, then everything else?

```
=IF('Attendance Tracker'!B52=0,"Y",IF('Attendance Tracker'!B52=1,"T",IF(OR('Attendance Tracker'!B52>=2,'Attendance Tracker'!D52>=0.1,'Attendance Tracker'!E52>0.1),"N")))
```

pseudo code

```
if B52 = 0 then Y (and exit) Else
    if B52 = 1 then T (and exit) Else
        if B52 > 2 OR D52 >= .1 OR E52 > .1 Then N Else
           FALSE
```

Suffice to say if B52 is 0 or 1 it won't check D52 or E52 and you'll get FALSE if nothing is true.